# What headers/META headers should I be using for an infinite link system like a calendar?

Tags: http-headers, calendar

I have a web calendar, all my own work. It works fine. But I see in the logs a bunch of search indexers go round and round and round trying to chase every link. It could go forward to the year 3000 month by month and day by day. I don't think the indexers should follow this as it doesn't serve much purpose. What HTTP headers or META headers should I apply to the calendar to let them know it is a calendar, but they shouldn't follow every link on those pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rel="nofollow"](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=96569) on all links that you don't want spiders to follow or index (i.e. days, months, etc.).

Use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to specify paths that you want them to ignore.

If your site is a web application, consider using robots.txt to disallow indexing of the whole app with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably simply `<a rel='nofollow' ...` on the calendar navigation links (as opposed to the events that link to specific events) would be fine.